# Protege min cardinality not adding member to defined class

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm new to Protege and ontology.
I have a defined class `UniqueScreening` that is 
`equivalent to -> FilmScreening and (hasTrack min 2 Track)`

then i create some members of Track that is `tr001` and `tr002`

and then I create a member of `FilmScreening` which is `fs001` that has Types 
`Film Screening
 hasTrack some {tr001}
 hasTrack some {tr002}`

and the `hasTrack` object property has domain `Track`

my question is, why `fs001` member is not inferred to `UniqueScreening` class?
does my class definition wrong?

Comment: Are `tr001` and `tr002` members of `Track`?

Comment: yes it is, sorry i forgot to made that clear, i edit my question

Comment: Declare tr001 and tr002 to be different individuals. By default they could be the same individual, so the cardinality would not be matched.

Comment: Cool, it's work. I didn't know they were the same by default, thank you very much. do you mind if you change your comment to an answer, so I could mark it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Ignazio:

Declare tr001 and tr002 to be different individuals. By default they could be the same individual, so the cardinality would not be matched.